# Assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm not sure why this is happening, I think I'm doing everything correctly.. Maybe someone can help point me in the right direction.

```
    unsigned short* x;

    int textLeft[16];

    x = shm->textLeft;
```

These are spaced out in the program so I didn't want to copy a bunch of code but if more is needed please let me know.

Shouldn't this work correctly without giving me the incompatible pointer type?

Comment: What is shm? How is it defined? if it is `int textLeft[16]`, then it's normal, `unsigned short*` is NOT the same as `signed int[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this should not work, because you're assigning an `int*` value to an `unsigned short*` variable, which causes undefined behavior per the C [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

The way to make this work without changing the types is to

1. cast the pointer, `x = (unsigned short *)(shm->textLeft);`, and
2. compile with GCC's `-fno-strict-aliasing` to turn the aliasing rule off.

But really, I strongly recommend you change the types to be compatible, since otherwise you're tying yourself to a single compiler's extensions to the C standard.

Comment: +1 In C, type errors doesn't really exist, it's just that you haven't cast things enough. </irony>

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: type errors do exist; without the `-fno-strict-aliasing` (a GCC-specific option), the compiler is free to break this code in any way it pleases.

Comment: And that was my attempt at humour.. My point was that C is not very strict with types.

Comment: @larsmans: You should have added: "*Don't try this at home!*" ...;-)

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: apologies, irony doesn't always pass through the internet unscathed.

Comment: This works, now I got an "Invalid Argument" error, I think it's because I need to clear the shared memory. Hopefully that's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
`unsigned short`
```

is not

```
`int`
```

So define

- `x` as `int *` or
- `textLeft[16]` as `unsigned short`

and things are ok.

Comment: You're right, I thought I had did that before but it took care of the error. But I remember now I get another error from something else. I get an "Invalid Argument" when before doing int it didn't have that.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `x` is a unsigned short pointer and `textLeft` is a signed integer. You are trying to assign signed integer address to unsigned short pointer.